# System.Security.Cryptography.Csp on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cryptoapi, ubuntu-16.04

I have ASP.Net Core 1.0.0 app using cryptography. I need to decrypt keys using `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. Visual Studio suggested adding `System.Security.Cryptography.Csp` version 4.0.0 to my dependencies. I accept, and on Windows it all works just fine. But when I deployed it on Ubuntu 16.04 `RSACryptoServiceProvider`'s methods started to throw `PlatformNotSupportedException` exception. Am I using the wrong assembly?
I found https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/v1.0.0/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Csp and there is 1.0.0 version. Is that what I need? How can I add it to my project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RSACryptoServiceProvider` is based on CryptoAPI, a Windows-specific unmanaged API. Since it's not available on Linux, a `PlatformNotSupportedException` exception is thrown at runtime.

Instead, consider referencing `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms` and using `RSA.Create()` to get an implementation compatible with your environment (on Linux, you'll get a `RSAOpenSsl` instance).

Comment: Thank you! `RSA` works fine. But still I don't get the point of including Windows-specific tools in Net Standart packages...

Comment: Not everyone needs or wants cross-platform support in .NET Core. Using implementation-specific packages allows using `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, `RSACng` or `RSAOpenSsl` directly, which enables advanced scenarios (e.g you can use a `CngKey` that relies on a specific key storage provider when using `RSACng`)